# Let $P(x)=b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_rx^r$ be a polynomial with real coefficients.Prove that the graph of $P(x)$ cuts the x-axis at the origin iff $m$ is odd.

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation

Let $P(x)=b_0+b_1x+\cdots+b_rx^r$ be a non zero polynomial with real coefficients. Let $m$ be the smallest number such that $b_m\neq 0.$ Prove that the graph of $y=P(x)$ cuts the x-axis at the origin (i.e. $P$ changes signs at $x=0$) if and only if $m$ is an odd integer.

The solution given is:

> Let $$P(x)=x^m(b_m +.....+b_rx^{r-m}),$$ let $$f(x)=b_m+....+b_rx^{r-m}.$$
> Now since  $b_m$ is non-zero,$f(0)>0$ or $f(0)<0.$
> Let $f(x)>0.$
>
> Now since a polynomial is continuous,there exists $t>0$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ belonging to $(-t,t)$ by the sign preserving property, so $f$ does not change sign in that interval.
>
> Hence, $P(x)$ changes sign at $0$ if and only if $x^m$ changes sign at $0$, which is possible if and only if $m$ is odd. The case for $f(0)<0$ is similarly done.

I need a bit help understanding this proof.

I dont understand, the part where it says,

"since a polynomial is continuous,there exists $t>0$ such that $f(x)>0$
for all $x$ belonging to $(-t,t)$ by the sign preserving property".

According to the version of sign-preserving property, I use is :

> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and $\alpha,\beta$ be two real numbers, such that $f(\alpha)>0$ and $f(\beta)<0$ (or, vice versa) then, $\exists$ at least one root or an odd number of real roots( counting multiplicity ) in the interval $(\alpha,\beta).$
>
> If $f(x)$ is a polynomial with real coefficients and $\alpha,\beta$ be two real numbers, such that $f(\alpha),f(\beta)>0$ and $f(\beta),f(\alpha)<0$ then, $\exists$ no roots or an even number of real roots( counting multiplicity ) in the interval $(\alpha,\beta).$

But I dont understand, how is this applied there (in the solution) ?

Even if I *assume* this part to be true, I still don't get how this part:

"Hence $P(x)$ changes sign at $0$ if and only if $x^m$ changes sign at $0$,which is
possible if and only if $m$ is odd.The case for $f(0)<0$ is similarly done." follows?

I feel, this line is itself ambiguous as, " $P(x)$ changes sign at $0$" makes no sense. I think, the author intended that $P(x)$ changes sign at some neighborhood of $0$. (But even though, it might be a standard way of phrasing this, which is unknown to me.) But what is with the reasoning, "only if $x^m$ changes sign at $0$,which is
possible if and only if $m$ is odd" ? This appears unclear, as well.

Comment: @AdamRubinson Yes, I just typed the thing mentioned in the paper. To be honest, this is an old contest problem. It will be helpful, if you suggest what improvements, I can make ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson the sentence is perfectly right. It means the smallest index such that $b_m$ is nonzero

Comment: @AdamRubinson Are you sure the question is wrong? Then I might delete this post, since it only clutters the site.  But should I gather some opinions ?

Comment: @AdamRubinson I posted this just like it was phrased.

Comment: The question is not wrong and neither the proof is. It needs probably a small explanation.

Comment: @AdamRubinson the two examples that you gave don't satisfy the conditions of the question. For both of them $m=0$ so it is not odd.

Comment: @ThomasFinley What they saay is that $P(x) = x^m \cdot f(x)$ where $f(0) \ne 0$, so $f(x)$ keeps the same sign on some neighborhood $(-t,t)$ of $0$, and therefore the sign of $P(x)$ around $0$ is dictated by $x^m$ and, of course, $x^m$ changes sign at $0$ iff $m$ is odd. The "*sign-preserving property*" in this context is that if a continuous function $f(x)$ is, say, positive at a point $f(a) \gt 0$ then it is positive on a neighborhood of that point $f(x) \gt 0$ for all $x \in (a-t,a+t)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\ve}{\varepsilon}$I am not sure why the sign-preserving property is needed here; I think continuity of $f$ is enough. Here is the argument, spelled out in rather too much detail.

We know $f(0)\neq 0$, so either $f(0)>0$ or $f(0)<0$. Without loss of generality, suppose $f(0)>0$. Then since $f$ is continuous, there is some $t$ such that $f(x)>0$ for all $x\in (-t,t)$. To see this, suppose $f(0)=\ve$; by the definition of continuity, there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|f(x) - f(0)|<\ve$ whenever $|x - 0|<\delta$. And $|f(x) - f(0)|<\ve$ is the same as $|f(x) - \ve|<\ve$, that is, $-\ve < f(x) - \ve < \ve$, and adding $\ve$ gives $0 < f(x) < 2\ve$, so in particular $f(x) > 0$ whenever $-\delta < x < \delta$. Now take $t = \delta$.

Now $P(x) = x^m f(x)$, and $f(x) > 0$ on $(-t,t)$. If $m$ is even, then $x^m>0$ whenever $t\neq 0$, and in particular on $(-t,0)\cup(0,t)$, so $P(x) = x^mf(x)$ is also positive on $(-t,0)\cup(0,t)$. This means that $P(x)$ doesn’t change sign at $0$. On the other hand, if $m$ is odd, then $x^m$ does change sign at $0$, and thus the same goes for $P(x)$. To see this, observe that for any $x\in (0,t)$, we have $x^m > 0$ and $(-x)^m < 0$, meanwhile $f(x) > 0$ and $f(-x)>0$. Thus $P(x) = x^mf(x) > 0$ and $P(-x) = (-x)^mf(-x) < 0$ for any $x\in (0,t)$. This says that $P(x)$ is negative on $(-t,0)$, positive on $(0,t)$, and zero at $0$.

The case of $f(0)<0$ is completely analogous, just with most of the inequalities flipped.